# Convergence of the algebraic properties of Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be two sequences. Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ (i.e. $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$) and $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be such that $\sum_{i = 1}^n |a_i − b_i|$ is finite (that is, converges). Then show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = a$.

Comment: Perhaps use this:  If series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n$ converges, then $t_n \to 0$. Maybe this is in your textbook just before the problem stated.

Answer (score 1):

Note $a_n\to a$ implies for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N_1$.

Then @GEdgar's hint implies there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-b_n|=|b_n-a_n|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N_2$.

So $|b_n-a|=|b_n-a_n+a_n-a|<|b_n-a_n|+|a_n-a|<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ by the triangle inequality. Hence $b_n\to a$ by definition of convergence.